# Problem 5.27 of Boyd & Vandenberghe's Convex Optimization

Tags: convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, duality-theorems

The following question is question no. 5.27 on p. 282 of Boyd & Vendenberghe's *Convex Optimization* (Cambridge University Press, 7th Printing, 2009):

> Consider the equality contrained least-squres problem
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> \text{minimize}\quad&\|Ax-b\|_2^2\\
> \text{subject to}\quad& Gx=h
> \end{align*}
> $$
> where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ with $\text{rank}(A) = n$, and $G \in \mathbb{R}^{p\times n}$ with $\text{rank} G = p$.
>
> Give the KKT conditions, and derive expressions for the primal solution $x^*$ and the dual solution $\nu^*$.

The following is the beginning of a solution to this problem that I found on the Internet:

> The Lagrangian is
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> L(x,\nu) &= \|Ax-b\|_2^2 + \nu^T(Gx-h)\\
> &= x^TA^TAx + (G^T\nu - 2A^Tb)^Tx - \nu^Th,
> \end{align*}
> $$
> with minimizer $x = -(1/2)(A^TA)^{-1}(G^T\nu-2A^Tb)$. The dual function is
> $$
> g(\nu) = -(1/4)(G^T\nu-2A^Tb)^T(A^TA)^{-1}(G^T\nu-2A^Tb)-\nu^Th
> $$

I don't understand why $x$ is $L$'s minimizer. If $x$ were the *global* minimizer of $L$ then, yes, I would understand why it must be the expression above. However, when we calculate the dual function $g$, we are supposed to minimize only over the feasible set of the primal problem (see excerpt below from p. 216 of the textbook), i.e. in this case over the set $\mathcal{D} = \{x :\ Gx=h\}$.

[image: Dual function]

Comment: I think the problem is convex, thus $x$ is a global minimizer. $D$ is the domain of the functions that satisfy the conditions in the constraints, not the feasible set of the problem. Please see the definition on pg. 215.

Comment: @Cherryblossoms: Makes sense. Thanks!